# Angular 2 Form Control Update

Tags: angular, form-control

How do I apply [ngModel] to the FormControl.
Lets say I have a form with some required fields, based on the changes in the selectbox I want to update the form Control?

Comment: Can u explain with bit code? Its unclear what ur asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best not to mix the two types of form reactive vs template meaning: `FormControl` with `ngModel`

if you're using reactive, you can use this to update a form controls value `this.myForm.get('SomeFormControl').patchValue('new value);`